# Exec() schtasks.exe via php script is not working in windows server 2012

Tags: php, windows, task, exec

I have php script like below. This script is used to create a scheduler task in windows via exec() function.

```
$taskName = "myTask"; 
$rhc = getcwd().'\3rdparty\rhc.exe';
$batfile = getcwd().'\3rdparty\update.bat';
$cmd = 'schtasks /query /TN "'.$taskName.'" >NUL 2>&1 || schtasks /create /tn "'.$taskName.'" /tr "'.$rhc.' '.$batfile.'" /sc DAILY /st 00:01 /f /RI 5 /du 24:00';
$output = exec($cmd,$output);
var_dump($output);
```

When i exec the php file in my localhost using xampp, it runs perfectly by showing the result below.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(67) "SUCCESS: The scheduled task "myTask" has successfully been created." }
```

But when i upload this script into my VPS that using windows server 2012, it has no return and the task isn't created. I tried exec the command manually using command prompt and it is success.

```
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "myTask" has successfully been created.
```

But when i exec the php file in my VPS, the task isn't created and it returns :

```
string(0) ""
```

I tried accessing my php file via localhost or via public ip and it returns same.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thankyou

Comment: do you need to host on windows?

Comment: @smith yeah. i need windows based server